# How to change color of debug variable names in Vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I know I can change the color of the values during a debug session in the sidebar by changing sideBar.foreground in my settings.json. But is there a way of changing the color of the variable names?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found out how yet?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

Add this to your settings.json.

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "debugView.stateLabelForeground": "#ff0000",
    "debugTokenExpression.string": "#a4ea85",
    "debugTokenExpression.name": "#82cdff",
    "debugTokenExpression.number": "#ff76e8",
    "debugTokenExpression.value": "#ffe14a"
  },
```

This was also very helpful https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#debug-colors

You can also modify the colors.

[image]